# AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Not sure how to get out of this already tried several things, can anyone help?

```
    Label(frame, text = "Nova senha:",font=self.fontePadrao,bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=2, column=0)
    self.nova_senha = Entry(frame)
    self.nova_senha.grid(row=2,column=1)
    self.nova_senha.delete(0, END)

def edit_records(self, novo_email,antigo_email,nova_senha, antiga_senha):
    if self.validation_edit():
        query = 'UPDATE Usuarios_Login SET email = ?, senha = ? WHERE email = ?'
        self.nova_senha = bcrypt.hashpw(self.nova_senha.encode(),bcrypt.gensalt())
        parameters = (self.novo_email,self.nova_senha,antigo_email)
        try:
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.msg['text']= 'Usuário editado com Sucesso!'
            self.edit_wind.destroy()
        except Exception as e:
            messagebox.showwarning("Aviso","Usuário já existente, tente outro!")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Erro", "Preencha os campos para validar a alteração!")
    self.get_users_login()
```

Comment: You should use `self.nova_senha.get().encode()`.  Also you have reassigned `self.nova_senha` to the result of `bcrypt.hashpw(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 I didn't understand where I should use self.nova_senha.get (). Encode ()? Tried on the () entry, but gave the following error - SyntaxError: cannot assign function call

Comment: `self.nova_senha = bcrypt.hashpw(self.nova_senha.encode(), ...)` should be, I think, `self.nova_senha.insert(INSERT, bcrypt.hashpw(self.nova_senha.get().encode(), ...))`.

Comment: @acw1668 it didn't work buddy.

Comment: You should post the complete error messages and not just say "It didn't work", otherwise we cannot help.  Also we cannot reproduce your error without a minimal workable code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: which line makes problem ?

Comment: in function `edit_records` you have two variables with similar name - local variable `nova_senha` and class variable `self.nova_senha` which is a Entry. It seems you use wrong variable - you use class variable `self.nova_senha` which is `Entry` but probably you need local variable `nova_senha` which probably is a string. And string has method `.encode()`. The same problem you may have with `self.novo_email` and local `novo_email`.